# Get All Exceptions in a Java Application

Tags: java, exception

how to get all Exceptions in a java application (have several classes and packages) in a place?
Example: create a class be get all Exceptions on other application classes

Comment: Didn't get you. you want to scan through classpath what are the available exception ?

Comment: please provide more details. do you want to catch all exceptions or just see what exception classes are available (only your packages or including java library)? are you talking about runtime and/or checked exceptions.

Comment: Exceptions are not the only things thrown. You can throw Errors and even Throwable or sub-classes (which are neither Errors nor Exception)

Answer (score 3):

As other already indicated, one option is to put your main method in a `try-catch` block

```
public static void main( String[] args ){
  try{
    //regular main code
  } catch (Throwable e){
    //do exception handling
  }
}
```

Another possibility is setting a default uncaughtExceptionHandler on the `Thread`(s) you are using with the [`Thread#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29) method.

Note that both solutions only allow you to 'handle all exceptions in one place' if they don't get caught at other locations in your application

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply have a class `ExceptionHandler` with 2 functions

```
void handleException(Exception e);
void handleThrowable(Throwable t);
```

and at every `try{}catch(Exception e){}` simply use `ExceptionHandler.handleException(e);`

To find out what Exception is being thrown, use `instanceof`

For eg.

```
if(e instanceof NullPointerException)
{
//whatver
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main class, you may have something like this:

```
try { } catch (Exception ex) { }
```

In your other classes, you should **throw** the exceptions, like:

```
public void example() throws Exception { }
```

If you throw the other classes' exceptions, you can deal with them just in the **main class**.

Comment: have you understood the question ?? whatdoes user986566 wants?

Comment: I guess user986566 wants to deal with all the application exceptions in just one class.

Answer (score 0):

The class [Exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) and its subclasses are a form of Throwable that indicates conditions that a reasonable application might want to catch.

If all you methods throw exception to the main calling method then you can catch all exceptions.

The hierarchy of exception classes commence from Throwable class which is the base class for an entire family of exception classes, declared in  `java.lang package` as `java.lang.Throwable`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

try {

```
//  block of code ...
```

} catch (Exception e){

```
// Do something with e
```

}